# How to pass an array of cl_mem buffers to OpenCL device

Tags: memory-management, buffer, parameter-passing, opencl

I want to pass an array of cl_mem buffers into one kernel, however it seems unfeasible. Anyone knows what's the point here? And if it's unfeasible actually, then how can I achieve that goal when I want pass many buffer objects into a kernel? Many thanks.

Comment: Other than clEnqueueNDRangeKernel() ?

Comment: What do you mean by clEnqueueNDRangeKernel? It's just to launch the kernel, not to pass parameters to the kernel. I use clSetKernelArg to pass parameters to kernel, shouldn't we?

Answer (score 0):

For a kernel such as

```
 kernelString = "__kernel void advect(" +
                "     __global float *x,"+
                "     __global float *y,"+
                "     __global float *z,"+
                "     __global float *vx,"+
                "     __global float *vy,"+
                "     __global float *vz,"+
                "     ... many arguments,"+
                "     __global float *x2,"+
                "     __global float *y2,"+
                "     __global float *z2,"+
                "     __global float *vx2,"+
                "     __global float *vy2,"+
                "     __global float *vz2)"+
                "{"+
                "..."+
                "}"+
```

Rather than

```
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, 0, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(girisDizisi0Buf));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, 1, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(girisDizisi1Buf));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, 2, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(girisDizisi2Buf));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, 3, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(girisDizisi3Buf));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, 4, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(girisDizisi4Buf));
    CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, 5, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(girisDizisi5Buf));
```

You can do same with your array in a loop

```
 for(int i=0;i<max;i++)
 {
      CL.clSetKernelArg(kernel0, i, Sizeof.cl_mem, Pointer.to(BufferYourArray[i]));
 }
```

if you are doing this in java's wrapper, you may need a String concatenator method to put the actual  arguments in kernel string. You can use 2-D arguments too. It shouldnt be a string problem in C/C++ 's wrapper.